# How can I scrape these Wikipedia tables with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the movies and release dates on this Wikipedia page across multiple tables:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Walt_Disney_Pictures_films

This is my code:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Walt_Disney_Pictures_films"
res = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
for items in soup.find('table', class_='wikitable').find_all('tr')[1::1]:
    data = items.find_all(['th', 'td'])
    try:
        movie = data[0].i.a.text
    except IndexError:
        pass
        print("{}".format(movie))
```

However, I'm only getting the movie titles from the first 1930s–1940s table. What I'm hoping for is two columns like this:

```
"Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs" | "December 21, 1937"
"Pinocchio" | "February 7, 1940"
"Fantasia" | "November 13, 1940"
```

How would I get this?

Comment: Look at the body of the response. Does it contain the data you are looking for? Then check `items` to see if it contains the elements you are trying to parse. Then check `data` to see if it is what you expect. For more tips on debugging your code, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you expect two columns (*and potentially a dataframe*), you can use [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

wiki_link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Walt_Disney_Pictures_films"
​
df = (pd.concat(pd.read_html(wiki_link), ignore_index=True)
            [["Title", "Release date"]].dropna(subset=["Title"]))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                               Title       Release date
0    Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs  December 21, 1937
1                          Pinocchio   February 7, 1940
2                           Fantasia  November 13, 1940
..                               ...                ...
618         Untitled Zootopia sequel                TBA
619                   World's Best ‡                TBA
620            Wouldn't It Be Nice ‡                TBA

[600 rows x 2 columns]
```